# Keytool Public/Private key pair for Android

Tags: android, google-play, rsa, public-key-encryption, dsa

I'm trying to create a public/private key pair using the keytool function so I can submit an Android app to Google Play. When I try to sign the app using the key I made, I get this error from jarsigner

```
jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: SHA1withDSA.  
SHA1withDSA must reference a valid KeyStore 
key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.
```

Same thing when I try using RSA. When I look at the keys for the keystore, all I see if the
     Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry

Not the public and private keys.

The command I used to create they key was

```
keytool -genkey -keystore nameofkeystore.keystore 
-alias coffitivity -keypass *passwordommitted* -storepass *thepasswordommitted*
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not actually 100% sure what I did to fix it, but this is what I did and now it works

```
keytool -genkeypair -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore 
-alias coffdroid -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Note: difference is I used "-genkeypair" instead of "genkey" even though they're supposed to be the same

Second: made a new unsigned .apk. This is likely what fixed it - so if you're hitting the wall, do that over.

Then Jarsigner

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 
-keystore my-release-key.keystore /Users/tommynicholas/Desktop/*apkname*.apk coffdroid
```

Comment: Another difference is that you specified RSA as the keyalg. Apparently the default is DSA.

Comment: True, but I had done tons of different variations with that, I should maybe edit it. Anyway, I should have just used the "Create Signed Application" function, but the tutorial doesn't mention that until AFTER the manual unsigned application method. Head slap moment for me!